# Highcharts change marker dynamically and individually

Tags: javascript, dynamic, colors, highcharts, marker

I'm using Highcharts and I'd like to know how can I change a few marker's setting (like `symbol`, `lineWidth`, `lineColor` and `fillColor`) of a certain number of values depending if they are larger (or not) a threshold.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/danielmorim/sxgL6/19/

I want to change all this marker's setting of all temperature data is larger than 20°C and less than 10°C.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify lineCOlor / lineWidth by access to graphic object and modify it by attr() function.

```
chart.series[0].graph.attr('stroke', 'red');
chart.series[0].graph.attr('stroke-width', 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following documentation. You can have your serie:

`serie = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];`

Also, you can have objects instead numbers. This objects can have multiple properties like: `fillColor`, `radius`, `symbol`.

So, you can modify the specific element in serie with something like:

```
serie[i] =  {
  y: serie1[i],         // This is the number 
  marker: {
    fillColor: 'red',
    radius: 5,
    symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/snow.png)'
  }
}
```

You can find the documentation here:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.marker
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols